# Google Cloud Function doesn't publish on PubSub, Timeout exceeded

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

On GCP (Google Cloud Platform), I've got a database stored on cloud SQL.

I have two Cloud functions:

1. make a request to the database (this request can have more than 1000 results) then publish the result on PubSub
2. web scraping thanks to puppeteer.

First cloud function's code:

```js
//[Requirement]
const mysql = require('mysql')
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager')
const ProjectID = process.env.secretID
const SqlPass = `projects/xxx`
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient()
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
const topicName = "xxxxxx";
//[/Requirement]

exports.LaunchAudit = async () => {
    const dbSocketPath = "/cloudsql"
    const DB_USER = "xxx"
    const DB_PASS = await getSecret()
    const DB_NAME = "xxx"
    const CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME = "xxx"
  
    //[SQL CONNEXION]
    let pool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 1,
      socketPath: `${dbSocketPath}/${CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
      user: DB_USER,
      password: DB_PASS,
      connectTimeout: 500,
      database: DB_NAME
    })
    //[/SQL CONNEXION]
    //set the request
    let sql = `select * from * where *;`
      //make the setted request 
    await pool.query(sql, async (e,results) => {
      //if there is an error send it
        if(e){
          throw e
        }
        //for each result of the query, log it and publish on PubSub ("Audit-property" topic)
        results.forEach(async element => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(element))
          await msgPubSub(JSON.stringify(element))
        })
    })    
}

async function msgPubSub(data){
  //console.log(data)
  const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(data)
  try {
    const topicPublisher = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(messageBuffer)
    console.log("Message id: " + topicPublisher)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error while publishing message: ${error.message}`)
  }
}
```

Problems:

1. Firstly, when it works, it takes a long time to publish the first message on the PubSub topic, something like 6 minutes. Why there is this delay?
2. Secondly, when I do a big request (something like 500+ results) I've got a Timeout error:

   ```
   Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 600000 milliseconds before any response was received.
   ```

I've tried to publish a batched message, add some memory to the cloud functions, use google-gax, but got the same result.

I'm using Node.js v10.

Second cloud function's message part code:

```js
exports.MainAudit =  async message => {
    const property = Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()
    const pProperty = JSON.parse(property)
    console.log(property)
}
```

`package.json` dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.6.0",
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^3.2.0",
    "google-gax": "^2.9.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

Log + Timestamp:
[image: log]

Comment: Do you have special config on your Cloud Function? Egress? Ingress? VPC connector?

Comment: Thanks for this response, but no it's a simple cloud function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the code is now, you are creating a new instance of a publisher for each message you publish. This is because `pubSubClient.topic(topicName)` creates an instance for publishing to the topic. Therefore, you are paying the overhead of establishing a connection for each message you send. Instead, you'd want to create that object a single time and reuse it:

```
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
const topicName = "xxxxxx";
const topicPublisher = pubSubClient.topic(topicName)
```

However, this still leaves an inefficiency in your application where you are waiting for each message to publish before starting the next publish due to the use of `await` on the `publish` call and the call to `msgPubSub`. The Pub/Sub client library can [batch messages together](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching)r for more efficient sending, but you'd need to allow multiple calls to `publish` to be outstanding to take advantage of it. You'd want to `await` on a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) of the list of promises returned from publishing.

Comment: Thanks for this, i saw that the instance was created by ```pubSubClient.topic()``` after posted this question, and it's way faster ! (i think it was the ```newPubSub()``` which create the instance)
thanks to explain to me tho !

and i'll do what you said with the batched messages, i understand now :)

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I had mis-read the Google docs https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching. The "Creates a client; cache this for further use" statement relating to `new PubSub()` is NOT a batch client. The output of `.topic()` is the batch client.